# How to perform cross account (using role arn's)in aws using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, roles

I was trying to connect to multiple aws accounts using arn's in list, but every time it is working only for the 1st arn in given list and for second it is failing.
I have deleted the first arn and again the same its working with second and failing with third.

```
    for arn in ROLE_ARN:
        print(arn)
        my_session = arn.split(':')[4]
        my_session = 'script-' + my_session 
        sts_client = STSConnection()
        assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
        role_arn=arn,
        role_session_name=my_session)

        os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key
        os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key
        os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token
        print (assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key)
        print (assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key)
        print (assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token)

        account_name = subprocess.getoutput("aws iam list-account-aliases --output text | awk '{print $2}'")
        print (account_name)
        account_id = (boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account'])
        print (account_id)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 432, in <module>
    main()
  File "aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 426, in main
    for_ports_and_iam()
  File "aws_security_cost_audit.py", line 402, in for_ports_and_iam
    role_session_name=my_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/sts/connection.py", line 384, in assume_role
    return self.get_object('AssumeRole', params, AssumedRole, verb='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 403 Forbidden
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid.</Message>
  </Error>
```

Comment: The problem is that you don't have any credentials defined in your code before trying to assume role. You are running this command: `assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role` without any credentials and hence the error.

Comment: Why are you calling the AWS CLI from a Python program?

Comment: At that time i was unable to find a way to find account name through boto3, so i have used aws cli.
Later i have figured out solution by:
`account_name=boto3.client('organizations').describe_account(AccountId=account_id).get('Account').get('Name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can include the aws credential with the command

```
for arn in ROLE_ARN:
    print(arn)
    my_session = arn.split(':')[4]
    my_session = 'script-' + my_session 
    sts_client = STSConnection()
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    role_arn=arn,
    role_session_name=my_session)

    print (assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key)
    print (assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key)
    print (assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token)

    credential = 'AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\"{}\" AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\"{}\" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\"{}\"'.format(
      assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token,
      assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key,
      assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key
    )

    command =  credential + " aws iam list-account-aliases --output text | awk '{print $2}'"
    print('command: ', command)
    account_name = subprocess.getoutput(command)

    print (account_name)
    account_id = (boto3.client('sts', aws_access_key_id=assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key, 
      aws_secret_access_key=assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key, 
      aws_session_token=assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token).get_caller_identity()['Account'])
    print('accountId: ', account_id)
```

Comment: I ran it with my credentials if something does not work  it must be the assumed_role_object

Answer (score 0):

After some googling i have fixed the issue by creating a `boto3.session` and calling other boto3 client functions with this name `session`.
Sample Codes:

```
session = boto3.Session(                                                                                                                                    
aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],                                                                                                                     
aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],                                                                                                             
aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken'])
```

```
for region in all_regions_list:                                                                                                                                 
ec2 = session.client('ec2', region_name=region)
```